# Is it possible to use JSSOR slider on e.g. DIV instead of IMG objects?

Tags: html, svg, jssor

I'm creating an automated events display system for a university department that creates posters based on SQL data. The idea is to create both SVG and PDF files of a poster so that the PDF can be used for printing, and the SVG can be displayed on an automatically updating web connected digital signage display (OK, OK, a TV on the wall).

I've got the SVG files formatted how I want them, but when I tried to use the slider libraries to display the .svg files, the formatting of certain elements goes haywire. I've narrowed this down to the fact that SVGs displayed using the IMG tag don't work properly. I've included the file into its own DIV, as it's an HTML5 project; if I move the 'u=image' to the DIV tag, the transition works OK but the SVG breaks once the transition is over (the text origins all seem to reset to upper left).

Just wondered if there was a way of doing this.

```
<!-- Slides Container -->
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 764px; height: 1080px; overflow: hidden;">

<?php 
    // DATA FROM SEMINARS_DETAIL
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `seminars_detail` LIMIT 4"; //Date >= NOW()
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {      
            $sem_id = $row["sem_id"];
            $file = "../images/posters/$sem_id.svg";
    //SVG not working properly. 
            echo "<div>";
            echo "<img u=\"img\" src=\"$file_th\" />";          
            echo "</div>";

    //Compared with...
    //Transition works, but text origin shifts when transition finishes.
            echo "<div u=\"image\">"; 
            include $file;
            echo "</div>";      
        }
    } else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post javascript code here as well.

Comment: Hi,I used the banner-slider demo code. Even using that code as is with the changes above to source the images, the problem remained. However, I've solved it by using IFRAME u='image' inside a plain DIV instead of DIV u='image'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please disable slideshow.

Also, please try use svg as background image.

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    <div style="background-image: url(l.svg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(2.svg);"></div>
    <div style="background-image: url(3.svg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The SVG no longer renders properly when I do this. I'm using a Chromium browser. On an iOS browser, there are no SVGs, and on Firefox based browsers, the SVG doesn't render correctly.

Comment: I have no idea. Anyway, please set $HWA to false, and remove responsive code.